# Using arrays for user input

Tags: java, arrays

I've looked around for answers for this but I cannot find it. My professor requires me to use an array.. not an arraylist

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int total = 30;
    String[] animalType = new String[total];
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int x = 0; x < total; x++) {
        System.out.println("Enter the type of animal " + x + 1);
        animalType[x] = input.next();

        for (int x1 = 0; x1 < total; x1++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the weight of the animal " + (x1 + 1));
            animalType[x1] = input.next();
        }

        input.close();

        System.out.println("Your friends are");
        for (int counter = 0; counter < total; counter++) {
            System.out.println(animalType[counter] + "\n" + animalType[counter]);
        }
    }
}
```

The prompt is.. allow user to enter the type of the animal and the weight of the animal and then output the average weight by animal type.
I'm new to java and do not know how to use arrays properly.

Comment: In this context, `input.close();` is unadvisable

Comment: So what's the exact problem? It is just to vague for a problem saying "do not know how to use arrays properly"

Comment: The "proper" way here is to create a "Animal" class, and create an `Animal[]`.

Comment: Could you explain further as to why I would have to create another animal class and couldn't put it all in one class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create a class for this purpose.

First, create another file called `Animal.java` and write a class that stores a `type` and a `weight`:

```
public class Animal {
    public String type;
    public int weight;
}
```

Of course, it would be better if you add getters and setters, but that would be too hard for you I think. I'll show the code anyways, but I won't use it in the example below.

```
public class Animal {
    private String type;
    private int weight;

    public String getType() {return type;}
    public void setType(String value) {type = value;}

    public int getWeight() {return weight;}
    public void setWeight(int value) {weight = value;}
}
```

Now you have this class, you can create an array of it.

```
Animal[] animals = new Animal[total];
```

And you need to fill the array in with animals!

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < total ; i++) {
    animals[i] = new Animal();
}
```

Actually, your for-loops are wrong. If you want to ask the user for the type first, then the weight, you should do it like this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < total; x++) {
    System.out.println("Enter the type of animal " + x + 1);
    animals[x].type = input.next();
}

for (int x1 = 0; x1 < total; x1++) {
    System.out.println("Enter the weight of the animal " + (x1 + 1));
    animals[x1].weight = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
}
```

Now you got the types and weights of the animals, hooray!

Answer (score 0):

You need a second array to store the weight(s). Something like

```
String[] animalWeight = new String[total];
for(int x1 = 0; x1 < total; x1++){
    System.out.println("Enter the weight of the animal "+(x1+1));
    animalWeight[x1] = input.next();  
}
```

Next, you print the values from your two arrays. And I would prefer calling `println` *twice* to embedding a `\n` (on some systems that can also cause issues, because they use other line termination characters such as `\r\n`). That might look something like,

```
// input.close(); // <-- Also closes System.in, can cause subtle bugs.
System.out.println("Your friends are");
for(int counter = 0; counter < total; counter++){
    System.out.println(animalType[counter]);
    System.out.println(animalWeight[counter]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried something like this as a previous attempt and when I did this it started outputting "Enter the type of animal" then it would do a loop of "Enter the weight of the animal".

Comment: Yes. That is what you have programmed it to do. You could prompt for both `weight` and `type` in one loop (one after the other).